# Solving non-homogeneous matrix exponential problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-exponential

$$\frac{d}{du}  \begin{bmatrix}a\\b \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}-x& y\\ -y&-x\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}cos(zu)\\ -sin(zu)\end{bmatrix}$$

P = $\begin{bmatrix}-x& y\\ -y&-x\end{bmatrix}$

And I have for u=0:
$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

Having proved that e<sup>Pu</sup> = e<sup>-xu</sup> $\begin{bmatrix}cos(yu)& sin(yu)\\ -sin(yu) & cos(yu)\end{bmatrix}$

My question is - how do I use this proof to solve this problem using the initial conditions.

Having thought about it - I consider that using the double angle formulae may help althought I haven't been able to formulate this.

Any help would be welcome.